# Is It Possible to Limit a Datatype Range in C

Tags: c, types, limiting

My question is about to limit the maximum range of a datatype so as to not exceed it is maximum value.
For example:

```
 unsigned char var1;
```

In this case minimum value for `var1` is 0, maximum value for `var1` is 255.

In my case for `var1` 200-255 are reserved value so it is necessary not to enter these values for safety reasons.

My question, is there any implementation method for C in order to limiting primitive data types range.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `if` statements and a `while` loop to check the input for the correct range.  C doesn't have anything built into the language to support specified minimum and maximum ranges.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Yes, i can but every time i dont want to check the range and also we have limited memory  (Embedded System) and is it a robust way using  `if`?

Comment: @Nazim: Unless the hardware supports this, which is unlikely, compiler support for limiting a type would work by inserting its own checks. So that would be no more efficient than writing your own checks in the source code, and it would probably be less efficient since the compiler would check after every operation, whereas you can write intelligent checks only where needed in the source code.

Comment: If you are working with safety-critical applications, there are entirely different rules you ought to be following for implementing software.

Comment: You could make the variable `static` in its own c file with a couple of externally accessible functions to read the value and set the value. The function that sets the value can return an error if the new value is out of range.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yes i am working on a safety-critical application. I follow some standards MISRA, CERT C. What would you suggest to me to do?

Comment: @Nazim There is no other way than `if`.

Comment: Using `assert.h` could be a possibility.

Comment: @Nazim Regarding your memory concern - even if you were able to define a type with the range `0 to 199` you would still need the same memory as you do when using a `char` - and if you currently need to check for the range multiple times you most likely have some possibilities in optimizing your code structure

Comment: Imagine you do `x+1` for such a datatype, what do you want to happen in that case? Do you want `x` to jump to its minimal value? Do you want to see an error message? Do you want your application to stop working? ...?

Answer (score 1):

The philosophy behind C is that the programmer is in the best position to know whether a range check needs to be performed, and is smart enough to write it if necessary.  There is nothing in the standard library that will do this for you.

You can write a simple macro for the test (easier than typing in the actual expression, and it sort of documents exactly what you're doing):

```
#define RANGE_CHECK(val,lo,hi) ((lo) <= (val) && (val) <= (hi)) // inclusive range check
```

and invoke it as necessary:

```
if ( RANGE_CHECK( x, 0, 200 ) )
  // do something with x
else
  // range violation, handle as necessary.
```

This is *extremely* primitive, but should at least point you in the right direction.  If you need to do this for floating point, you'll want something way more robust.

Comment: This accepts 200 as valid, but the question states 200 is reserved. Also, `RANGE_CHECK` is an ambiguous name, since it does not indicate whether it is true for values in range or for values out of range.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Bummer, missed that.  Oh well.